# jsFiddle: Default tab

Tags: jsfiddle

Is it possible to specify the jsFiddle default tab in embed mode?

For example, I created [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamadaliakbari/tP2tW/4/), which has no JavaScript, and embedded it into my blog: http://blog.rastasoft.ir/node/46/

But because I had no JavaScript in it, the default tab is empty. I want to set the HTML tab as default. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is fully documented in [Embedding the fiddle - Changing Tabs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/embedding.html#changing-tabs)

> In example if to show the result as the first tab add `result,js,html,css/` to the `URL: src="http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/NmudS/embedded/result,js,html,css/"`